# ear deployment error in glassfish is no protocol when i use digester

Tags: java, linux, glassfish-3, ear, apache-commons-digester

I am using glassfish to deploy my .ear application, the application which works fine glassfish windows and linux at offshore but when we try to deploy the same application in production which is running on linux environment am getting the following error

```
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /glassfish/Sharedlib/ExtConfig.xml
```

As this is a production issue so critical from our side so please I expect some one to suggest on this to figure out the problem.

Please reply if you would like know anything else releated to this issue.

Glassfish Version - 3.1.2.2 build5
Jdk               - 1.6

Error Log(server.log):

```
[#|2013-11-21T15:35:41.036+0530|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: ge.ifm.common.exception.GenericInterfaceException: IOException-->Occured while calling parse of Digester Class.Exception Message is -->no protocol: /glassfish/Sharedlib/ExtConfig.xml
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:375)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:219)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:78)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.run(AppServerStartup.java:253)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.doStart(AppServerStartup.java:145)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.start(GlassFishImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishDecorator.start(GlassFishDecorator.java:63)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishImpl.start(OSGiGlassFishImpl.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: ge.ifm.common.exception.GenericInterfaceException: IOException-->Occured while calling parse of Digester Class.Exception Message is -->no protocol: /glassfish/Sharedlib/ExtConfig.xml
    at ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener.contextInitialized(IFMCacheListener.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /glassfish/Sharedlib/ExtConfig.xml
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:567)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.pushXMLReader(XMLReader.java:234)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:208)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:755)
    at ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener.contextInitialized(IFMCacheListener.java:79)
    ... 35 more
|#]
```

Comment: well, you seam to pass the value `/glassfish/Sharedlib/ExtConfig.xml` as a URL somewhere (web.xml or from a class). If you want a relative path, I would add a '.'; probably you want to reference a file on your file system, try with a absolute URL to solve the issue if it is urgent. Something like `file://.../glassfish/Sharedlib/ExtConfig.xml`.

Comment: Hi Matthias, Thanx for your valuable suggestion but adding "file" before to the filepath is throwing error with some other places where we used to load xsl templates using javax xml transform transformerconfiguration. Also i came to know that the problem is xalan jar is not converting the filepath to URL object so have downloaded the xalan-2.7.1 and used in my application so now it's working fine. Thanks and Regards pappu